# how can i use request parameter in struts2 if tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, http-request-parameters

i have a link like this :`http://localhost:8080/ESA/login.jsp?login=failed`
in end of above link a set a parameter with name `login` and value `failed`.
how i can use this parameter in jsp page with struts if tag. I use following code but it don't work.

```
<s:if test="%{#parameters.login='failed'}">
    <div class="error">
        <s:text name="user.login.failed"></s:text>
    </div>
</s:if>
```

Comment: Did you try with a double-equals?

Comment: Also if you are confused about the type of the OGNL expression ie: What is a #parameters.login? simply append .class ie: #parameters.login.class then if the method/operator does not make sense on that type it will not work.

Comment: @DaveNewton double-equals not works too.

Comment: What about #params.login?

Comment: @DaveNewton not works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with

```
<s:if test="%{#parameters.login[0]=='failed'}">
```

The two problems were in your code:

1. The `=` sign is an assignment, not equals `==`;
2. Parameters are saved
   in the `Map<String, String[]>`, so each parameter could have
   multiple values and accessed by the specifying an index.

   The last option also described here: [why doesn't the `if` tag evaluate params properly](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/why-doesnt-the-if-tag-evaluate-params-properly.html).

Comment: Could you explain this please.

Comment: @AleksandrM Is this explained to you?