# Struts does not evaluate if statement correctly. How to evaluate struts 2 s:if?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, struts2, radio-button

I got three Radio Buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="is_active" value="true">Active&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="is_active" value="false">Inactive&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="is_active" value="both" checked>Both<br>
```

And then some JSP. When I write:

```
<%=request.getParameter("is_active")%>
```

I get "both", "true" or "false" in my HTML. But when I write:

```
<s:if test='%{#request.getParameter("is_active") == ("both")}'>
```

The output of <%=request.getParameter("is_active")%> is always: true or false or both. One of this three options.
The server does not go into the if block even if I choose "Both" radiobutton. What is wrong?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817767/how-can-i-use-request-parameter-in-struts2-if-tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817767/how-can-i-use-request-parameter-in-struts2-if-tag)

Comment: Why do you have all parameters in the request?

Comment: @Braj: my if statement already looks exactly like the one in the link you provided: <s:if test="%{#parameters.login[0]=='failed'}">, so I do not understand your comment. Can you please explain?

Comment: @RomanC: What do you by all parameters?

Comment: "both", "true" or "false", also what is the order they printed?

Comment: @RomanC: I still do not understand what are you asking about. I just put one parameter into request.getParameter("is_active") because this are radio buttons.

Comment: If you place one parameter, how could you get all three ones?

Comment: @RomanC: Still I do not know what are you talking about ;(. If I select 'both' in the radiobutton, I would like to display something, but the if does not work, the code processing do not go into the if block when I debug. Only one selection can be made in one time

Comment: What is the output of `<%=request.getParameter("is_active")%>`?

Comment: @RomanC: The output of <%=request.getParameter("is_active")%> is always: true or false or both. One of this three options.

Comment: Why do you use parameters from request? Map your inputs into action variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Java comparison inside the OGNL expression. Strings are compared in Java using `equals` method.

```
<s:if test='#request.getParameter("is_active").equals("both")'>
```

or with OGNL comparison

```
<s:if test="#parameters.is_active[0] == 'both'">
```

Comment: The behaviour is the same, I mean the server is not going into the if block, even if the statement is true.

Comment: That is the value is not `'both'` or `"both"`, so it's evaluated correctly to `false`.

Comment: It is, the value is "both" but still is is not going inside.

Comment: What is the `s` prefix for?